# Stamp duty for a couple with one person owning less than £40000 of property overseas

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, home-ownership, stamp-duty

Suppose a couple is buying a house in the UK. One partner is a first time buyer, another owns a share of property overseas with value less than £40,000 (and nothing else). Suppose they are buying a house for £400,000. What then will be the amount of Stamp Duty?

Answer (score 6):

The UK government has published [guidance notes](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/759714/Stamp_Duty_Land_Tax_relief_for_first_time_buyers_-_guidance_note.pdf) on Stamp Duty that answer these questions and more. That document makes it clear that.

- To count as a first time buyer you must not have ever owned any residential property anywhere in the world before and you must be buying the property as your main residence.
- If you're buying the property jointly and one of you does not qualify for first time buyer status then neither of you can get the first time buyer discount.

Comment: Agreed. The fact that the property is overseas, and that the person only owns a part of it - even if they only owned £1 worth of it - makes no difference at all, it prevents you as a couple from qualifying for first time buyer discount.

Comment: Robert, @Vicky, many thanks! I wonder, would it be possible in such case for one partner to buy the property and qualify for a first time buyer?

Comment: Thanks Robert! I wonder, in such situation, if only one partner applies for the mortgage (the one who doesn't own a property), can the money for the other partner be used in the deposit?

Comment: I was about to suggest that you asked that as a separate follow up question, then I found https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/145851/mortgage-for-a-couple-where-one-partner-is-not-a-first-time-buyer - linking for other readers' benefit.